# Не срабатывает скрипт после перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Есть скрипт, который прилепляет блок к верху страницы, после ее прокрутки до места расположения блока. Он работает, но если пролистать страницу , например, до середины, а потом перезагрузить ее, то скрипт не работает, класс не добавляет. Сам скрипт:

```
$(function(){
    var PostFixedbar = $('#post-fixed-bar').offset().top;  
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if( $(window).scrollTop() > PostFixedbar ) {
            $('#post-fixed-bar').addClass('fixed');
        } else {
            $('#post-fixed-bar').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
});
```

Если после перезагрузки страницы покрутить мышкой, бывает срабатывает, бывает нет.
Сайт на Wordpress.

Кто знает решение?

Comment: @m0d Ознакомтесь - [правка с удалением приветствий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4386/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8).

Answer (score 1):

У вас проверка надо отображать блок или нет вызывается при прокрутке. Просто добавьте её вызов при загрузке страницы

```
$(function(){
    var PostFixedbar = $('#post-fixed-bar').offset().top;
    var checkBar = function(){
        if( $(window).scrollTop() > PostFixedbar ) {
            $('#post-fixed-bar').addClass('fixed');
        } else {
            $('#post-fixed-bar').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    }
    $(window).scroll(checkBar);
    checkBar();
});
```

Comment: Какие-то мы синхронные)

Comment: @Qwertiy если бы мы были ковбоями - жив остался бы я

Comment: Ну 20 секунд :)

Comment: Интересно работают такие варианты. Скрипт включается на том месте, где была перезагружена страница :) При прокрутке вниз работает, а когда вверх крутишь - нет ) Чувствую, что и это можно победить) как?

Comment: @Лео  Вангую - когда вы загружаетесь с уже имеющейся прокруткой, в  `var PostFixedbar = $('#post-fixed-bar').offset().top;` получается другое значение. Вам надо ккаим-то образом сделать так, чтобы оно было одинаковое в обоих случаях.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    var PostFixedbar = $('#post-fixed-bar').offset().top;  

    function update(){
        if( $(window).scrollTop() > PostFixedbar ) {
            $('#post-fixed-bar').addClass('fixed');
        } else {
            $('#post-fixed-bar').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    }

    $(window).scroll(update);
    update();
});
```